# Overflow oddity

Tags: css

What is the status on overflow-x and overflow-y?  Whenever I give overflow a value, and inspect that element, the browsers tend to split this into overflow-x and overflow-y.  However, trying to explicitly state this gives nothing.

For example, on my math class page: http:math.davehampson.net the grades tab is very wide, and I want it to scroll within the `<div>` There is no height declared, so it stretches down, and I get a horizontal scroll bar.

By problem is that I also get an unneeded vertical scroll bar.  If I change overflow:scroll to overflow-x:scroll, then nothing happens.  The table is displayed in full width, and the entire page scrolls.  Which, because the body is black, does not show up.

Is there a way for me to eliminate this inactive vertical scroll bar?

Thanks, Dave

Comment: i'm not sure at all, but i think that within a div, if you have a horiz scroll, you automatically get a vert scroll. again, about 10% confidence in that answer :)

Comment: I've seen seen vertical scroll bars w/o horizontal ones many times.  Normally I forbid any horizontal scroll bars in web pages, but this is an exception where I think it works.  Provided the scrolling is confined by a `<div>`

Answer (score 2):

overflow:auto only adds a scroll bar when the content within it exceeds the allocated space.

So if you only need a horizontal scroll, make sure the height of the content is less than the height of the enclosing div, if that makes sense.

Comment: Except I need the height to "flow" with the contents.  I could probably use javascript to grab the `<div>` height, then increase it by a few pixels, but I'd rather have a pure css solution.